# RRD print the timestamp of the last valid data

Tags: health-monitoring, rrdtool, rrd

I have a rdd database storing ping response from a wide range of network equipments
How can i print on the graph the timestamp of the last valid entry in the rrd database, so i can see if a host is down when did it went down
I use the folowing to creade the RRD file.

```
rrdtool create terminal_1.rrd -s 60 \
DS:ping:GAUGE:120:0:65535 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2880
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`lastupdate`](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdlastupdate.en.html) option of rrdtool.

Another solution exists if you only have one file per host : don't update your RRD if the host is down. You can then see the last updated time with a plain `ls` or `stat` as in :

```
ls -l terminal_1.rrd 
stat --format %Y terminal_1.rrd
```

In case you plan to use the caching daemon of RRD, you have to use the [`last`](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdlast.en.html) command in order to flush the pending updates.

```
rrdtool last terminal_1.rrd
```